# Выражение "под мухой"

Tags: фразеология

Почему о подвыпившем человеке говорят "под мухой"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была такая карточная игра "Муха", где само это слово означало выигрыш, удачу. То есть, изначально речь шла о напившемся от радости выигрыша человеке.

Answer (score 2):

У выражения «ходить под мухой», «быть под мухой» есть совершенно четкое происхождение. Вместо кабаков, бывших простыми питейными заведениями, Петр I повелел открыть по всей России трактиры, где люди не только пили бы, но еще и активно закусывали. Для привлечения клиентов, которым нововведение не очень-то понравилось, было решено первую рюмку наливать бесплатно.
Но, во-первых, трактирщики были жадными. Во-вторых, размера тогдашних рюмок вполне хватало для того, чтобы почувствовать легкое, приятное опьянение. В-третьих, клиенты трактиров взяли моду выпивать бесплатную первую рюмку и идти себе дальше. Поэтому специально для трактиров были заказаны рюмки вместимостью 10-15 мл — а это примерно одна столовая ложка, чтобы и трактирщики не разорились на бесплатной выпивке, и клиентам хотелось бы выпить еще, но уже за свой счет. Новые рюмки тут же окрестили «мухами». А посетители трактиров начали ходить от заведения к заведению, чтобы выпить как можно больше бесплатных первых «мух». Отсюда и пошло выражение «ходить под мухой».

**[источник](http://ideivk.ru/2016/06/20/o-vyrazhenii-khodit-pod-mukhoy/)**

Comment: Версия не подтверждает и (что бессмысленно) повторяет уже имеющиеся. Раздел о достопримечательностях и сувенирах не удовлетворяет требованиям сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Сомнительно.

Выражение «быть под мухой» связано с традицией выпивания. Мухой назывался небольшой стаканчик. Рюмку с названием «муха» бесплатно подавали посетителям многих трактиров. Именно отсюда пошло выражение «под мухой» - когда чуть-чуть выпил. Отсюда появились и похожие выражения «муху раздавить, муху зашибить».

Answer (score 1):

Вот, на переднем плане, та самая рюмка "муха", точнее три )) Объем чуть ли не чайная ложка. Во исполнение указа о первой бесплатной рюмке кабатчики минимизировали убытки - наливали вот такую "муху".
Фото из музея завода в Гусь Хрустальном.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда известно, что это именно она, муха?

Comment: В музее написано, что так называли? Кстати, Завада подтверждает ответ Владимира! ;)